# Toggle background image of a link for accordion

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, background-image, accordion

I'm trying to get a links background image to toggle or swap on click for an FAQ accordion expand/contractable div using javascript.

I've gotten things working based on this jsfiddle example (http://jsfiddle.net/QwELf/)

You can see my page working here (http://bit.ly/1hfgcGL)

The problem comes in when you click one of the toggle links a 3rd time. It gets the wrong background image and is then out of sync with how it should look.

Right arrow > for contracted state and downward arrow for expanded state are how they should be but the opposite shows up.

It seems to work just fine in the jsfiddle on the 3rd or more clicks any idea what's going wrong with mine?

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeArrow(element){

var arrow = element;

if(arrow.className == 'background_one'){

  arrow.className = 'background_two';

} else {

  arrow.className = 'background_one';

}

}
</script>
```

CSS

```
.background_one { text-decoration: none; padding-left: 26px; background: url(http://skmgroupwork.com/suntrust/landingpages/307m/chevright.gif) center left no-repeat;}
.background_two { text-decoration: none; padding-left: 26px; background: url(http://skmgroupwork.com/suntrust/landingpages/307m/chevdown.gif) center left no-repeat;}
```

HTML

```
<a class="background_one" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo4"    onClick="changeArrow(this)">If I transfer my balance to a new Access 3 Equity Line, what will my interest rate be?</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if it has class, not if it is, as you have several on times. As you use jQuery you can use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeCLass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). You might also want to look at [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

```
function changeArrow(element) {
    var $arrow = $(element);
    if ($arrow.hasClass('background_one')) {
        $arrow.removeClass('background_one');
        $arrow.addClass('background_two');
    } else {
        $arrow.removeClass('background_two');
        $arrow.addClass('background_one');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly and your description helps me understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the className *also* contains the class `collapsed` the second time it's clicked.

I used IE's debugger and found this:

[image]

Perhaps you could use `contains` instead of equals, like the following (untested, but should work):

```
function changeArrow(element){
    element.className = (arrow.className.contains('background_one') ? 
                          'background_two' : 
                          'background_one');
}
```

Comment: The extra class did not seem to be an issue. My script was just doing the wrong function.

Comment: @TerriSwiatek Actually, the extra class *was* the problem. You were using `=` which was a direct string comparison. `hasClass` is *not* a direct string comparison; it sees if the class exists in className, which is essentially what the `contains` string comparison does.